# Using Processing to create visual buttons

Tags: serial-port, processing

How would I use Processing to make visually-appealing buttons that when clicked will send data through a serial port? Is this possible in Processing or would I need to use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really talking about two different things:

**How do I draw a button?**

How you do this depends entirely on you. You could just draw a rectangle using the `rect()` function or a circle using the `ellipse()` function, then put some text in there with the `text()` function. Or you could load an image file and draw that using the `image()` function. It's entirely up to you.

**How do I do something when the user clicks a button?**

This is a little trickier, but still pretty easy in Processing. You would use the `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables and `if` statements to check whether that position is inside one of your buttons, and then do the correct thing if so.

Processing comes with several examples of buttons, you should take a look at those.

Another option is to use a GUI library, but that's probably overkill if you just want to show a couple buttons.